# Is CSS mostly used for HTML controls, not for asp.net server controls?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.net.

1) I know that CSS can be used in asp.net server controls, but is CSS mostly used for HTML controls? To the asp.net server control, should I use it's inline appearance settings?

2) Also, to the Asp.NET MVC model, should I use HTML only or as less as Asp.net server control?

3) To the ASP.NET web form model, should I use jQuery's functions rather than it's controls? Or should I only use raw javascript instead of jQuery if I use ASP.NET web form model?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use CSS. If you choose to style the server controls with its inline appearance settings, you will have to do it every time for every control. With CSS, you can add a class and style all of them with one definition (See [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).
2. Use the server controls. Unless you define the HTML controls as `runat="server"` (which, by the way, makes them server controls), you will not be able to access the HTML controls in your code-behind. Remember that, ultimately, the ASP.Net server controls get rendered as HTML controls to the page your users use.
3. Use what works best for the situation. If a jQuery UI control does the job better and/or faster, use it. Otherwise, use your own. Likewise, if a jQuery function does the job better and/or faster, use it. Otherwise, take care of it with plain JavaScript or in your code-behind.

The main ideas I'm trying to express here are to use the best tool for the job. I develop in ASP.Net at my job, and I use a mix of native JavaScript, jQuery, CSS, (plain HTML, ASP.Net server controls, code-behind, etc.) to get the job done. I try to follow principles of "best practices" which include things like Separation of Concerns, the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and "Be forgiving of what you accept and strict with what you emit" (I forget what this one's called, but it came from one of the designers of TCP/IP).

Answer (score 0):

for question 1, you can use css for asp.net controls. there is a cssclass property that allows you to choose a class. also .net controls render as html controls so you can control them that way as well (e.g. gridview renders as a table)

Answer (score 0):

This is an opinionated question/response, but the best I can give you:

1) Always use CSS when possible rather than inline styling.  Use the CssClass property for this.  If you must set control properties, use ASP.Net themes to centralize look/feel in one place.

2) Not sure I understand this one, but will only say:  Don't use ASP.Net Server controls in an MVC project.  Defeats the whole purpose of MVC.

3) For Web Forms, use Jquery for client side interactivity or ajax postbacks to the server when possible (will be a lot lighter than UpdatePanel typically).  But you still should use the WebForms postback mechanism when submitting forms in most places.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is really a wrapper around HTML Controls. It does not have extensive functions like other Scripting languages for example PHP, Python etc. To get jobs done in ASP.NET, you really have to use C# or VB.NET.

All ASP.NET Controls are rendered as HTML Controls. You can use inline CSS or embedded or global css, just like you would with any other html control. The end result would be the same.

You should always use ASP.NET controls on .ASPX pages otherwise, your form will not be submitted and that it take your considerable time to troubleshoot.

You can use JavaScript, jQuery, anything you want with ASPX pages. Microsoft itself uses Javascript in ASP.NET.

Comment: ASP.Net is the web framework/stack that sits on top of .net framework.  It's not a wrapper around html controls.

Comment: You can design your own server controls or user control.  You can even inherit from built in controls and extend them how you want.  Server controls give you low level control over everything that is emitted back to the browser, and user controls are simple re-usable snippits of html/javascript/other server controls that you can quickly re-use in multiple places on your web site.

Comment: It is .NET framework but essentially is a wrapper around HTML controls. In php you use HTML + PHP. In ASPX, there is no HTML controls. They are simply disguised as ASPX controls. There are no functions in ASPX but you can create a funtion. It has to be C# or VB.NET funtion. ASPX is simply a wrapper, nothing much.